# Unable to delete workspace in Hudson

Tags: java, hudson, cvs

I have a project imported from cvs to Hudson. When I try to wipe out workspace containing some files with non-ascii symbols or whitespaces I get something like that:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete <FILENAME>
    hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:260)
    hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:302)
    hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:221)
    hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
    hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:221)
    hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
    hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:221)
    hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
    hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:221)
    hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:301)
    hudson.FilePath$9.invoke(FilePath.java:821)
    hudson.FilePath$9.invoke(FilePath.java:819)
    hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:1899)
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    ...
```

Is there any solution for that? Or at least is there a way to ignore some files/folders during the import from cvs repository?

I use Hudson ver. 1.392 on a server with Debian Linux. On the same Hudson on my local pc with Windows XP this problem didn't occur.

Comment: Ensure that the hudson user has delete permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in your tomcat connector as described [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Tomcat#Tomcat-i18n)?

I also came across this Hudson JIRA:

[HUDSON-3030: Hudson fails to delete files with foreign characters in the file name](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3030)

This Jira sounds like the problem you are having, but it has been closed because it was not related to hudson.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is discussed in [Eclipse bug 36322](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363222), related to stale lock files from NFS.

One suggested workaround is to add a cleanup command to the shell section of the build job, something like `find /path/to/hudson/jobs/<jobname> -name ".nfs*" -exec rm {} \;`.